# iOS App rejected due to review team misunderstanding its use. Do i resubmit?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

My app binary was rejected due to paragraph 2

2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

The review team misunderstood how to use the app since it is location based. I explained more about how to test it and proposed another solution in the resolution center and i don't need to change anything in the binary.
Do i need to "Submit the app for review"? Or wait for the review team to respond first?

Edit: To be more specific what i am asking is: I send the extra info to the resolution center. Do i leave the submission as it is with app status rejected, or do i resend the same binary for review along with the info provided?

Comment: You can make an appeal in resolution center and also upload some screenshot or videos to make them understand. No need to submit binary again. Submit it for review

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I wont reupload the binary but do i have to resend it for review? The button is enabled again. Or do i leave it with status: rejected and wait?

Comment: No need to again archive and re-upload. Just make an appeal in resolution center and hit submit for review button. In the appeal column, you can also upload snapshots, videos in order to make them understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resubmit the same thing. Sometimes the reviewers don't take enough time to review. I've had a friend who has submitted the same exact thing twice. The First time it didn't go through, but with the second reviewer it did.

Comment: This is a direct answer to the question. I'm telling him to leave it as is and submit. IDK how much clearer can I be.